# Dictionaries/hashmaps setting in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, hashmap

I've been studying Python for a few days now on the famous tutorial [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/). At a certain point, talking about dictionaries on [Exercise 39](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html), there is a couple of little functions that read like this:

```
def hash_key(aMap, key):
    """Given a key this will create a number and then convert it to
    an index for the aMap's buckets."""
    return hash(key) % len(aMap)

def get_bucket(aMap, key):
    """Given a key, find the bucket where it would go."""
    bucket_id = hash_key(aMap, key)
    return aMap[bucket_id]
```

Now, what sounds obscure to me is the way the bucket id is decided on the first function.
Assuming I wanted to find the bucket for the key "myCoolKey", Python would go: *hash('myCoolKey') % len(aMap)*, which in case of *len(aMap)* being "256" would result "139".
So reading on afterwards, if I'm not being wrong, 'myCoolKey' is going to be put assigned to aMap slot 139.

Now:

1. Is there a particular reason I can't see for this being done?
2. What about collisions? Isn't it possible that being the map limited, two keys could result being assigned the same slot while other slots still being unused at the same time?

Comment: 1. What do you mean? Why wouldn't it be done? 2. No, although multiple keys could be in slots in one bucket while other buckets are empty.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually, the second answer is "no". If you look at the rest of the code he linked, you'll see that each bucket is a list of (key, value) pairs.

Comment: @murgatroid99 ah, sorry, didn't realise "slots" was distinct from "buckets". Editing.

Comment: No, I mean 1. what's the reason for that, assuming there is one? And then: 2. If so, what is the purpose of all this complicated mechanism? Probably I'm not skilled enough to get it.

Comment: It's probably worth watching ["the mighty dictionary"](http://pyvideo.org/video/276/the-mighty-dictionary-55) to understand this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The purpose of a hash table is to provide you with immediate lookup times. The `%` modulo function is used to ensure that you will always have a key that is within the bounds of your hash table (so there are no `IndexError` issues). There is often additional hashing before this (such as in your case) to try and ensure that the keys are as evenly distributed as possible, to reduce collisions.
2. Yes, it's possible for a *general* hash table. Hash tables can resolve this by 1) re-hashing the value to put it into another slot, 2) just putting it in the next available slot, or 3) putting a list of values into that slot, instead of just a single value. It appears that your code goes with option 3.

Comment: One other strategy that hash tables sometimes use, instead of putting a list of values in a bucket, is if there are too many collisions in a bucket, switching to a balanced tree in that bucket. HashMap in Java 8, for example, switches to a red-black tree once the number of collisions in a bucket passes a threshold.

Comment: @DavidConrad I hadn't seen that before personally, but it certainly makes sense for really dense hash tables.

Comment: I see. Indeed in this example there are buckets that are basically other lists, and the only chance of collision (as far as I understood) is when dealing with same bucket (==same hash) and same key inside bucket. Makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link gives a good walkthrough of how the dictionary or hashmap works for exercise 39 - https://nicolasgkruk.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/understanding-making-your-own-dictionary-module-from-learning-python-the-hard-way-exercise-39/